Spring Data JPA | Unable to save child record
I'm having two tables Parent and Child, where child has a reference to Parent. Using Spring Data JPA I'm trying to make entries in these two tables, but Spring inserts record only in Parent table.
Below is the code for reference:

Parent class

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent", schema = "min_max")
@SequenceGenerator(
        name = "parentSeq",
        sequenceName = "min_max.PARENT_ID_SEQ"
)
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "parentSeq")
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name", length = Integer.MAX_VALUE)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade =  CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "compositeKey.parent")
    private Set<Child> children = new LinkedHashSet<>();

}


Child class

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "child", schema = "min_max")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Child {
    @EmbeddedId
    private ChildPK compositeKey;

    @Column(name = "name", length = Integer.MAX_VALUE)
    private String name;

    public Child() {

    }
}


ChildPK

@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Embeddable
public class ChildPK implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3512694928135551826L;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id")
    private Parent parent;

    @Column(name = "some_column", nullable = false, length = 10)
    private String someColumn;

}


ParentRepository:

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ParentRepository extends JpaRepository<Parent, Integer> {

}


Service Method

Parent p = new Parent();
p.setName("C");
Set<Child> childSet = new HashSet<>();
Child c = new Child();
ChildPK cpk = new ChildPK(p,"ABC")l
c.setcompositeKey(cpk);
childSet.add(c);
p.setChildren(childSet);
parentRepository.save(p);

What am I missing? Any help is much appreciated as I have tried multiple things to fix this.
Note: If I don't have a composite key, then it works without any issues and entry in both tables is created.

My suggestion is you do not need the mapping in your ChildPk.  Just put @Column private Integer id instead of the mapping.  You already have your mappings between entities.

Also it would be helpful to provide any errors, exceptions that are occurring in the logs.  That will be helpful in finding the issue with your code.
